# The rectangle doesn't move upward when method is called

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm into graphics now and I am trying to create a rectangle that moves with key events. 
Here is the code:

Class to create the rectangle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Snake
{
class RectangleClass
{
   // private Rectangle _rectangle;
    private int _positionX;
    private int _positionY;
    private int _height;
    private int _width;



    public RectangleClass(int positionX, int positionY, int height, int width)
    {
        _positionX = positionX;
        _positionY = positionY;
        _height = height;
        _width = width;
    }
    public int PositionX
    {
        get
        {
            return _positionX;
        }
        set
        {
            _positionX = value;
        }
    }

    public int PositionY
    {
        get
        {
            return _positionY;
        }
        set
        {
            _positionY = value;
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
        set
        {
            _height = value;
        }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _width;
        }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
        }
    }


    public Rectangle CreateRectangle()
    {
         Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(PositionX, PositionY, Width, Height);
            return rectangle;
    }



    public int MoveYUpWard()
    {
        return PositionY += 10;
    }

    public int MoveYDownWard()
    {
        return PositionY -= 10;
    }


  }
}
```

and the form:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


    namespace Snake
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            RectangleClass rc;

            public Form1()
            {



                InitializeComponent();
                rc = new RectangleClass(30, 90, 50, 50);

            }

            private Graphics g;



            private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {




                if (g == null)
                {
                    g = this.CreateGraphics();
                }
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 10);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rc.CreateRectangle());

            }



            private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("UP");
                    //Sets position y to 100
                    rc.MoveYUpWard();




                }
            }
```

I have debugged the code and the method MoveYUpWard() does change the position of the rectangle when arrow key is pressed but the position of the rectangle is the same.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Don't store `Graphics` instances.  Instead, use `e.Graphics`.

Comment: Are you sure that the paint event is getting fired?

Comment: The form doesn't know to repaint - call Invalidate on it.

Comment: @SLaks why shouldn't I do that? Is there any reason? And I have implemented singleton on that.

Comment: This class would be much shorter with autoproperties.

Comment: I'd like to point out that instead of handling its own events, your Form should override OnPaint, OnKeyUp and so on.

Comment: @mrlucmorin okay. I overrided processDialogKey and now I am able to hold down my arrow and move the object constantly.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is here. try this code.

```
public int MoveYUpWard()
{
    PositionY -= 10;
    return PositionY;
}

public int MoveYDownWard()
{
    PositionY += 10;
    return PositionY;
}


private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("UP");
        //Sets position y to 100
        rc.MoveYUpWard();
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I realize that after I executed the program. It wasn't the main problem though. Thanks for your help anyway